# How to read text file with columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a csv file like this:

```
Model   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
Acura   CSX/EL  MDX NSX RDX RSX/Integra Other
Alfa Romeo  145/146/147 156/159 166 4C  Brera   GIULIETTA   GTV/GT  Mito    Spider  Other
Aston Martin    DB7/DB9 DBS One-77  Rapide  Vanquish    Vantage Virage  Zagato  Other
Audi    A1  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  Q3  Q5  Q7  R8  S3/RS3  S4/RS4  S5/RS5  S6/RS6  S7/RS7  S8
```

Where the first column is the model of a car, and the other columns are makes of that car.

The number of makes is dynamic. I want to save the makes for each car and tried to do it like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
class CsvToJson:
    def __init__(self, csvFilePath):
        with open(csvFilePath, 'rU') as csvFile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter= ';',
                                    quotechar = '|', dialect='excel')
            final = dict()
            for row in spamreader:
                makes = list()
                print ', '.join(row)

k = CsvToJson(csvFilePath = 'carsModelsMakes.csv')
```

But I am stuck about how to get the column.

after the great answer, i got this results

[image]

how can i remove these empty values please

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a class to do this, just a function:

```
import csv
import json

def CsvToJson(csvFilePath):
    with open(csvFilePath, 'rU', newline='') as csvFile:
        final = {}
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter='\t') # change delimiter if needed
        next(reader)  # skip header
        for row in reader:  # now removes "empty" row values
            final[row[0]] = [value for value in row[1:] if value]

    return json.dumps(final, indent=4)

k = CsvToJson('carsModelsMakes.csv')
print(k)
```

Output:

```
{
    "Acura": [
        "CSX/EL",
        "MDX",
        "NSX",
        "RDX",
        "RSX/Integra",
        "Other"
    ],
    "Aston Martin": [
        "DB7/DB9",
        "DBS",
        "One-77",
        "Rapide",
        "Vanquish",
        "Vantage",
        "Virage",
        "Zagato",
        "Other"
    ],
    "Audi": [
        "A1",
        "A3",
        "A4",
        "A5",
        "A6",
        "A7",
        "A8",
        "Q3",
        "Q5",
        "Q7",
        "R8",
        "S3/RS3",
        "S4/RS4",
        "S5/RS5",
        "S6/RS6",
        "S7/RS7",
        "S8"
    ],
    "Alfa Romeo": [
        "145/146/147",
        "156/159",
        "166",
        "4C",
        "Brera",
        "GIULIETTA",
        "GTV/GT",
        "Mito",
        "Spider",
        "Other"
    ]
}
```

Comment: i update my question depending on your answer , could you check please

Comment: note the delimeter is this `reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter= ';')`

Comment: The delimiter in a CSV file is the character that separates fields in a row. (Technically, if it's not a comma, it's not actually CSV, but that's not the point.) The delimiter in your input file can't be a `;`, because that character doesn't exist in your input at all. It looks like your data is tab delimited (which is `\t`, the delimiter matrineau used), although the tabs got converted to spaces by stackoverflow.

Comment: Marco: I used `delimiter= '\t'` because that was the separator you actually had in the sample _data_ posted in your question (which also doesn't have a bunch of empty values in each row). Change it to `delimiter= ';'` and see if that helps. If not, I can easily modify my answer to remove all the empty values encountered in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> myFile = 'test.txt'
>>> df = pd.read_csv(myFile, sep=",", header=0)
>>> df
    Model  A  B  C
0  Model1  a  b  c
1  Model2  a  b  c
2  Model3  a  b  c
```

Getting the "Model" column

```
>>> df['Model']
0    Model1
1    Model2
2    Model3
Name: Model, dtype: object
```

Reformatting to JSON

```
>>> df['Model'].to_json()
'{"0":"Model1","1":"Model2","2":"Model3"}'
```

Comment: i can't use a third party libraries

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli bummer ... `pandas` is excellent when working with/manipulating data frame like data :(

Comment: thank you , the library is great but the policy of the company prevents me from using it. thanks for your unerstanding and appreciate your help +1 for u